# Call javascript function from main page

Tags: javascript, html, frame

I've a framed page, called `main.xhtml`. Inside that page is the following code block:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
javascriptCode
</script>

<frameset cols="234,*" border="0" frameborder="no">
   <frame src="LeftPage.html"  />
   <frame src="RightPage.html" name="main" />
</frameset>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I call the javascriptCode from inside LeftPage.html or RightPage.html?
For example, I'll click on a button on LeftPage.xhtml and javascriptCode in the main page will be triggered.
Thanks.

Comment: not the duplicate one, i just added extra example about what i want. tnx

Comment: Someone still uses framesets?

Comment: While frames may not be the best choice (understatement), see if the info on this page helps you along: http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/javascript/scriptingframes.html

Comment: @DavidBrainer-Banker : Understatement of the year

Answer (score 0):

```
window.parent.fn()
```

calls the function `fn` defined as a global variable in the parent frame.

It works because, in the browser, `window` is the global object whose properties alias global variables, so `window.parent` points to another frame's global object so its properties are the globals for code loaded in that other frame.